# As Google Data List APIs has been deprecated, then which api to use for Google sites?

Tags: c#, google-data-api

As Google Data List APIs has been deprecated by Google, so we can use "Google Drive APIs" for Google Drive but what about Google Sites? I am currently using Google.Gdata.client.dll reference to work with Google Sites.

Comment: Hi, we are also in the same situation and we didn't find any link which describes the alternative for Google Sites for Google.Gdata.Client.dll

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google is maintaining the following page to help people who use its APIs keep track of their transition away from gdata: 
https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory

As of 06/01/2015, there is no replacement for the Google Sites API.

Answer (score 0):

You carry on using the existing GData API according to the page provided by @froggythefrog:

- [GData API Directory](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory)

I can see that a lot of GData API's have been deprecated and most newer versions aren't based on it any more but it says that Google Sites Data API is unaltered, specifically "GData version is still live. No replacement API."

This might mean that it's days might be numbered but at the moment it is the current API.

I can't see any mention saying that the GData API as a whole is outright deprecated.